# Azure Search .NET SDK throws InvalidOperationException SerializationBinder with Newtonsoft.Json version higher than 9.0.1

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm getting an error message System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.SerializationBinder' from Azure .NET SDK after update NewtonSoft.Json to version 10.0.3

Here is part of StackTrace

```
at Microsoft.Azure.Search.JsonUtility.CopySettings(JsonSerializerSettings baseSettings)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.JsonUtility.CreateDeserializerSettings[TSearchResult,TSuggestResult,TDoc](JsonSerializerSettings baseSettings)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperations.DeserializeForSearch[T](String payload)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperations.<DoContinueSearchWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__21`3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperationsExtensions.<SearchAsync>d__17`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

I'm using latest version Microsoft.Azure.Search and .Net Core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3441). Please make sure you're using version 5.0.0 of Microsoft.Azure.Search (or newer versions as they become available).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Search vesion 3.0.5 but issue still persists, so I'm trying to figure it out with binding redirects

Comment: We just released 5.0.0. Please give it a try and let us know if it helps.